# Clean my maven local repository

Tags: maven

i am trying to find a automatic way to clean my Maven local repository.
i am already tried using the purge plugin but he didn't work as i expected (was no consistent). then i tried the remove-project-artifact plugin. This plugin work as i expected, but then i had new problem, i have more then one Maven project that use the same local repository, so when a few build run in the same time (only one of the build operator the remove-project-artifact plugin), some of the build are failing because of this plugin.
so my question is if someone had the same problem and managed to solve it?

Comment: Why do you need that? It sounds like you are working on a CI solution (like Jenkins?) Yes?

Comment: Yes i am working on Jenkins , but i prefer to add a change in my POM then to add a scrip that Jenkins will run. For the long term it will be easier to maintain..

Comment: It sounds like you are using the global repository of the jenkins instead a repository locally to the appropriate job. If you do that you can clean that up separately. Furthermore there existing plugins to clean up job repositories.